# Drawing graph structures using python and matplotlib only?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph-theory

To draw a set of objects in a breadth first search manner

To get this out of the way in the beginning, I'm quite a noob at programming in general so please pardon the obviously noobish things I would've done in the following project.

The goal of this project is to get a graph structure if you give it a table of nodes, their descriptions and the nodes that it is connected to. The hurdle though is that I cannot use any external libraries to do this apart from matplotlib.

The input would look something like this:

[inputs as a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKCMD.jpg)

The expected output should be something along the lines of this: (note this diagram ignores the dimensions)

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogkff.jpg)

The logic which I developed is:

Convert the raw list data into an class object which has all the attributes from the list.

2)Proceed to searching the nodes in a breadth first manner

3)Put the sequence of spaces that the BFS searched into a list

4)Then draw out the spaces as they appeared in the list (note the distance between them is necessary for what I need it for)

How far I got:

I figured out everything till step no 3. The problem I have is that I have to set a x and y position for each space now.

To break down what I have in mind is that :

If the first node is an entry type node then it draws it out in the middle of the maximum breadth of the graph

Count the number of external connections it has and then draw them out as (maximum breadth /number of connections , incrementing through them. So, the living room has none so it will draw it out in the middle. The living room has 5 connections ( out of which one has already been drawn i.e. the entry so we iterate through the next set of four spaces only moving in the x axis) Then we step up the y and draw again.

To execute this I intended to have a loop which goes though the ordered list of spaces and have a counter. The process:

1)if the node encountered is one of the type of entry node then we draw out that node and set the counter to number of connections.

2)if the counter is 1 then we move the Y axis up. and draw out that space

3)if the counter is > 1 then we divide the the counter value by the maximum depth value

The problem I have:

The example shown here only takes into account that we have one entry.

2)The ordering of spaces is wrong when using the counter method.

3) The counter method doesnt draw out the termination nodes properly.

And when I actually write it down in python I get this, which means I've clearly failed:

[The output which I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjsPs.jpg)

The script as it stands now:

[Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/KPSFh1ix)

And at this point I'm out of ideas as how I should actually fix this problem. Any help is much appreciated :)

```
#imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from math import pi , sin

#raw data
connections = ['1', '0,2,5,7,8', '1,3', '2,4', '3', '1,6', '5', '1', '1']
indices = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
spaceTags = ['entry ', 'living area', 'dining area', 'Kitchen', 'Utility', 
            'Bedroom1', 'Toilet attached', 'Toilet common', 'Bedroom2']
area = ['1', '40', '20', '15', '6', '20', '6', '6', '20']
minimumDimension = ['1', '5', '4', '3', '2', '4', '2', '2', '4']

#define the space class
class Space(object):
    def __init__(self,index,spaceName,connections,area,minimumDimension):
        self.index = index
        self.spaceName = spaceName
        self.connections = connections
        self.area = area
        self.ydim = minimumDimension
        self.xdim = (self.area / self.ydim)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.isExplored = False
        self.polarAngle = 0
        self.spaceType = 0 
        # 0= not assigned ; 1 = entry; 2 = intermediate; 3 = termination

    def ObjectAttributes(self):
        return (self.index,
                self.spaceName,
                self.connections,
                self.area,
                self.y,self.x,
                self.xdim,self.ydim,
                self.isExplored,
                self.spaceType)

#definations
#process integers
def convert_to_int_vals (input_list):
    output_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(input_list):
        output_list.append(int(input_list[i]))
        i += 1
    return output_list

#process floats
def convert_to_float_vals (input_list):
    output_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(input_list):
        output_list.append(float(input_list[i]))
        i += 1
    return output_list

#process 2D lists for connections
def process_2d_connections (input_list):
    output_list = []
    for item in input_list:
        if len(item) <= 1:
            lst = []
            lst.append(int(item))
            output_list.append(lst)
        else:
            var = item
            var = (var.split(','))
            var = convert_to_int_vals(var)
            output_list.append(var)
    return output_list

#make data into objects i.e. spaces
def convertDataToSpaces(index,spaceTag,connections,area,minimumDimension):
    print('Processing data...')
    if (len(index)==len(spaceTag)==len(connections)==len(area)==len(minimumDimension)):
        i = 0
        output_list = []
        while i < len(spaceTag):
            space = Space(index[i],spaceTag[i],connections[i],area[i],minimumDimension[i])
            output_list.append(space)
            i += 1
        print('Done.')
        return output_list
    else:
        print('Number of lists dont match')

#find first node
def FindFirstNode(spaceList):
    output = 'null'
    for item in spaceList:
        if item.spaceName == 'entry ' or item.spaceName =='entry':
            item.spaceType = 1
            output = item

    if output == 'null':
        print('No entry defined. Please define entry!')

    return output

#Calculate hypotenuse
def calculate_hypotenuse(arg1,arg2):
    val = ((arg1**2)+(arg2**2))**(0.5)
    return val

#Calculate max hypotenuse
def calculate_max_hypotenuse (spaceList):
    outputval = 0
    for item in spaceList:
        var = calculate_hypotenuse(item.xdim,item.ydim)
        if var > outputval:
            outputval = var
        else:
            outputval
    return outputval

# Note this is a FIFO list
def FindAndQueueNextNode(spaceList,searchNode,queue):
    searchNode.isExplored = True

    if len(searchNode.connections) == 1:
        if searchNode.spaceName == 'entry ' or searchNode.spaceName =='entry':
            searchNode.spaceType = 1
        else:
            searchNode.spaceType = 3
    elif len(searchNode.connections) > 1:
        searchNode.spaceType = 2
    else:
        searchNode.spaceType = 0

    for item in spaceList:
        if ( item.index in searchNode.connections) and (item.isExplored == False) :
            queue.append(item)

# Calculate the position based on the dimension (inputs are the object dimensions and current floating dim) 
def CalculatePosition(currentx, currenty, space):
    spaceXdimadjusted = (space.xdim / 2)* -1
    spaceYdimadjusted = (space.ydim / 2)* -1
    adjustedx = currentx + spaceXdimadjusted
    adjustedy = currenty + spaceYdimadjusted

    return (adjustedx,adjustedy)

#core algorithm
def coreAlgorithm(spacesList):
    ## variable holding max hypotenuse distance
    grid_dimension = int((calculate_max_hypotenuse(spacesList))*(1.5))
    print('Grid dimensions are : ' + str(grid_dimension) + (' units'))

    ## create empty processing variables
    processingQueue = []
    orderedListOfSpacesInBFS = []
    maxTreeWidth = 0

    ## find the first space
    firstSpace = FindFirstNode(spacesList)
    orderedListOfSpacesInBFS.append(firstSpace)
    print('The first node is : ' + str(firstSpace.spaceName) +
        '; Index being : ' + str(firstSpace.index))

    ## queue the next space
    FindAndQueueNextNode(spacesList,firstSpace,processingQueue)

    ##start while loop (while queue length loop  > 0)
    while len(processingQueue) > 0 :
        if len(processingQueue) > maxTreeWidth:
            maxTreeWidth = len(processingQueue)
        else:
            maxTreeWidth = maxTreeWidth
        item = processingQueue.pop(0)
        orderedListOfSpacesInBFS.append(item)
        FindAndQueueNextNode(spacesList,item,processingQueue)

    ## second loop to loop through spaces and draw them
    maxXDepthDimension = grid_dimension * maxTreeWidth
    ypos = grid_dimension 
    counter = 0

    while len(orderedListOfSpacesInBFS) > 0:
        item = orderedListOfSpacesInBFS.pop(0)

        if item.spaceType == 1:
            xpos = maxXDepthDimension / 2
            (item.x , item.y) = CalculatePosition(xpos,ypos, item)
            ypos += grid_dimension
            counter = len(item.connections)

        elif counter == 1:
            xpos = maxXDepthDimension / 2
            (item.x , item.y) = CalculatePosition(xpos,ypos, item)
            ypos += grid_dimension
            counter = len(item.connections) - 1

        elif counter > 1:
            xpos = (maxXDepthDimension / counter)
            (item.x, item.y) = CalculatePosition(xpos, ypos, item)
            counter -= 1



#draw lines as a separete method

#core algorithm preprocess
def coreAlgorithmLoop (spaces_list):

    #check object feasibility and if the algorithm can run.
    print('Starting algorithm...')
    startrun = False
    floatingvartoggle = 1

    for item in spaces_list:
        if type(item) == Space:
            floatingvartoggle = floatingvartoggle * 1
        else:
            floatingvartoggle = floatingvartoggle * 0

    if floatingvartoggle == 1:
        startrun = True
    else:
        print('Objects should be spaces.')

    #start of  core-algorithm.
    if startrun == True:
        coreAlgorithm(spaces_list)

#implementation
#pre-process data
indices = convert_to_int_vals(indices)
spaceTags = spaceTags
connections = process_2d_connections(connections)
area = convert_to_float_vals(area)
minimumDimension = convert_to_float_vals(minimumDimension)

#initialize processing
listOfSpaces = convertDataToSpaces(indices,
                                spaceTags,
                                connections,
                                area,
                                minimumDimension)
coreAlgorithmLoop(listOfSpaces)

#matplotlibtester - start
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim((0, 100))
ax.set_ylim((0, 70))


for space in listOfSpaces:
    var = space.area
    print(space.ObjectAttributes())
    rect = patches.Rectangle((space.x,space.y),
                            space.xdim,space.ydim,0,
                            linewidth=1,
                            edgecolor='r',
                            facecolor='none')
    ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.show()
#matplotlibtester - end
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is awkward but just in-case it helps someone, The method to solve it is:

- Create the attributes explored from and depth
- Then in the queue keep track of how the node was explored and what it's depth is (the current searchnode is assigned to the items getting queued, the searchnode's depth is equal to the depth of the node that it was explored from +1
- Using this create a layered chart to understand where each object goes, (depth is the row/ tier/ level number) and the instance that the object is in that level is the column number

This is easier to do with another class.Here is the modified version of the code:
(note it draws an asymmetric chart which is okay for my purposes and I've still not solved the issue of more than one starting points which is okay for now)

```
#imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from math import pi , sin

#raw data
connections = ['1', '0,2,5,7,8', '1,3', '2,4', '3', '1,6', '5', '1', '1']
indices = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
spaceTags = ['entry ', 'living area', 'dining area', 'Kitchen', 'Utility', 
            'Bedroom1', 'Toilet attached', 'Toilet common', 'Bedroom2']
area = ['1', '40', '20', '15', '6', '20', '6', '6', '20']
minimumDimension = ['1', '5', '4', '3', '2', '4', '2', '2', '4']

#define the space class
class Space(object):
    def __init__(self,index,spaceName,connections,area,minimumDimension):
        self.index = index
        self.spaceName = spaceName
        self.connections = connections
        self.area = area
        self.ydim = minimumDimension
        self.xdim = (self.area / self.ydim)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.isExplored = False
        self.isExploredFrom = 0
        self.Depth = 0
        self.spaceType = 0 
        # 0= not assigned ; 1 = entry; 2 = intermediate; 3 = termination
        self.CentroidX = 0
        self.CentroidY = 0

    def ObjectAttributes(self):
        return (self.index,
                self.spaceName,
                self.y,self.x,
                self.Depth)

class DrawingStructure(object):
    def __init__(self,Depth):
        self.Depth = Depth
        self.numberOfInstances = 0
        self.count = 0
#definations
#process integers
def convert_to_int_vals (input_list):
    output_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(input_list):
        output_list.append(int(input_list[i]))
        i += 1
    return output_list

#process floats
def convert_to_float_vals (input_list):
    output_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(input_list):
        output_list.append(float(input_list[i]))
        i += 1
    return output_list

#process 2D lists for connections
def process_2d_connections (input_list):
    output_list = []
    for item in input_list:
        if len(item) <= 1:
            lst = []
            lst.append(int(item))
            output_list.append(lst)
        else:
            var = item
            var = (var.split(','))
            var = convert_to_int_vals(var)
            output_list.append(var)
    return output_list

#make data into objects i.e. spaces
def convertDataToSpaces(index,spaceTag,connections,area,minimumDimension):
    print('Processing data...')
    if (len(index)==len(spaceTag)==len(connections)==len(area)==len(minimumDimension)):
        i = 0
        output_list = []
        while i < len(spaceTag):
            space = Space(index[i],spaceTag[i],connections[i],area[i],minimumDimension[i])
            output_list.append(space)
            i += 1
        print('Done.')
        return output_list
    else:
        print('Number of lists dont match')

#find first node
def FindFirstNode(spaceList):
    output = 'null'
    for item in spaceList:
        if item.spaceName == 'entry ' or item.spaceName =='entry':
            item.spaceType = 1
            output = item

    if output == 'null':
        print('No entry defined. Please define entry!')

    return output

#Calculate hypotenuse
def calculate_hypotenuse(arg1,arg2):
    val = ((arg1**2)+(arg2**2))**(0.5)
    return val

#Calculate max hypotenuse
def calculate_max_hypotenuse (spaceList):
    outputval = 0
    for item in spaceList:
        var = calculate_hypotenuse(item.xdim,item.ydim)
        if var > outputval:
            outputval = var
        else:
            outputval
    return outputval

# Note this is a FIFO list
def FindAndQueueNextNode(spaceList,searchNode,queue):
    searchNode.isExplored = True

    if len(searchNode.connections) == 1:
        if searchNode.spaceName == 'entry ' or searchNode.spaceName =='entry':
            searchNode.spaceType = 1
        else:
            searchNode.spaceType = 3
    elif len(searchNode.connections) > 1:
        searchNode.spaceType = 2
    else:
        searchNode.spaceType = 0

    for item in spaceList:
        if ( item.index in searchNode.connections) and (item.isExplored == False) :
            item.isExploredFrom = searchNode.index
            item.Depth = searchNode.Depth + 1
            queue.append(item)

# Calculate the position based on the dimension (inputs are the object dimensions and current floating dim) 
def CalculatePosition(currentx, currenty, space):
    spaceXdimadjusted = (space.xdim / 2)* -1
    spaceYdimadjusted = (space.ydim / 2)* -1
    adjustedx = currentx + spaceXdimadjusted
    adjustedy = currenty + spaceYdimadjusted

    return (adjustedx,adjustedy)

#def return only unique values in a list
def ReturnUniqueValues(input_list):
    output_list = []
    for i in input_list:
        if i not in output_list:
            output_list.append(i)

    return output_list

#core algorithm
def coreAlgorithm(spacesList):
    ## variable holding max hypotenuse distance
    grid_dimension = int((calculate_max_hypotenuse(spacesList))*(1.5))
    print('Grid dimensions are : ' + str(grid_dimension) + (' units'))

    ## create empty processing variables
    processingQueue = []
    orderedListOfSpacesInBFS = []
    maxTreeWidth = 0

    ## find the first space
    firstSpace = FindFirstNode(spacesList)
    orderedListOfSpacesInBFS.append(firstSpace)
    print('The first node is : ' + str(firstSpace.spaceName) +
        '; Index being : ' + str(firstSpace.index))

    ##initialize first space
    firstSpace.Depth = 0
    firstSpace.isExploredFrom = 0  
    FindAndQueueNextNode(spacesList,firstSpace,processingQueue)

    ##start while loop (while queue length loop  > 0)
    while len(processingQueue) > 0 :
        if len(processingQueue) > maxTreeWidth:
            maxTreeWidth = len(processingQueue)
        else:
            maxTreeWidth = maxTreeWidth
        item = processingQueue.pop(0)
        orderedListOfSpacesInBFS.append(item)
        FindAndQueueNextNode(spacesList,item,processingQueue)

    #second loop for figuring out the depth and column number to draw
    DepthList = []
    uniquelist = []
    DrawingList = []

    for item in orderedListOfSpacesInBFS:
        DepthList.append(item.Depth)

    uniquelist = ReturnUniqueValues(DepthList)

    for item in uniquelist:
        var = DrawingStructure(item)
        DrawingList.append(var)

    copyList = orderedListOfSpacesInBFS

    while len(copyList) > 0:
        space = copyList.pop(0)
        for thing in DrawingList:
            if int(thing.Depth) == int(space.Depth):
                thing.numberOfInstances += 1

    ##actually setting the values to later draw
    for item in spacesList:
        rowNum = item.Depth
        rowData = 'null'

        for entry in DrawingList:
            if rowNum == entry.Depth:
                rowData = entry

        colNum = rowData.count
        rowData.count += 1

        xpos = rowNum * grid_dimension
        ypos = colNum * grid_dimension

        item.CentroidY =   xpos
        item.CentroidX =   ypos 

        (item.x, item.y) = CalculatePosition(ypos,xpos,item)


#draw lines as a separete method
def DrawConnectionLines(spacesList):
    for item in spacesList:
        centroid = [item]

#core algorithm preprocess
def coreAlgorithmLoop (spaces_list):

    #check object feasibility and if the algorithm can run.
    print('Starting algorithm...')
    startrun = False
    floatingvartoggle = 1

    for item in spaces_list:
        if type(item) == Space:
            floatingvartoggle = floatingvartoggle * 1
        else:
            floatingvartoggle = floatingvartoggle * 0

    if floatingvartoggle == 1:
        startrun = True
    else:
        print('Objects should be spaces.')

    #start of  core-algorithm.
    if startrun == True:
        coreAlgorithm(spaces_list)
        DrawConnectionLines(spaces_list)

#implementation
#pre-process data
indices = convert_to_int_vals(indices)
spaceTags = spaceTags
connections = process_2d_connections(connections)
area = convert_to_float_vals(area)
minimumDimension = convert_to_float_vals(minimumDimension)

#initialize processing
listOfSpaces = convertDataToSpaces(indices,
                                spaceTags,
                                connections,
                                area,
                                minimumDimension)
coreAlgorithmLoop(listOfSpaces)

#matplotlibtester - start
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim((-10, 60))
ax.set_ylim((0, 70))

xvals = []
yvals = []

for space in listOfSpaces:
    print(space.ObjectAttributes())
    rect = patches.Rectangle((space.x,space.y),
                            space.xdim,space.ydim,0,
                            linewidth=1,
                            edgecolor='r',
                            facecolor='none')
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    xvals.append(space.CentroidX)
    yvals.append(space.CentroidY)

plt.scatter(xvals,yvals)

plt.show()
#matplotlibtester - end
```